# Google charts column filtering

Tags: debugging, google-visualization

I am trying to filter a Google line chart columns and using the code shared here in [Google Charts-Code for Category Filter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17967387/google-charts-code-for-category-filter)

It all works well however I have a number of columns and would like to have the chart start with just one column displayed and allow the user to add in any of the additional columns as needed.

What I've found is that if I play with the initState variable to set it to the one column I want to display initially, it will have that column shown in the selector section but still displays all the columns initially until I select an additional column when it hides the rest and just displays the two I have selected.

So then I tried turning off this part of the code:

```
// put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)<br>
for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
 columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
 initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(i));
}
```

and replacing it with

```
columnsTable.addRow([1, data.getColumnLabel(16)]);
initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(16));
```

which sets the column i'm after (column 16) as the selected column in the selection list but removes the other columns from the list of available columns and still displays all 16 columns.

How can I set this up so it displays the single selected column's data initially yet still gives the ability to pick other columns from the selector?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to keep the `columnstable.addRow` call inside the `for` loop, as it populates the DataTable used to provide the list of columns.  You can set the `selectedValue` variable as you have it:

```
// put the columns into this data table (skip column 0)<br>
for (var i = 1; i < data.getNumberOfColumns(); i++) {
    columnsTable.addRow([i, data.getColumnLabel(i)]);
}
initState.selectedValues.push(data.getColumnLabel(16));
```

In order to make the chart draw properly with the initial selection, we need to make a small adjustment to the structure, putting all of the updating code into its own function, and then calling that as necessary:

```
function setChartView () {
    var state = columnFilter.getState();
    var row;
    var view = {
        columns: [0]
    };
    for (var i = 0; i < state.selectedValues.length; i++) {
        row = columnsTable.getFilteredRows([{column: 1, value: state.selectedValues[i]}])[0];
        view.columns.push(columnsTable.getValue(row, 0));
    }
    // sort the indices into their original order
    view.columns.sort(function (a, b) {
        return (a - b);
    });
    chart.setView(view);
    chart.draw();
}
google.visualization.events.addListener(columnFilter, 'statechange', setChartView);

setChartView();
```

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/WaUu2/157/.

Comment: Thank you for that, I thought it would need to be restructure somehow but just couldn't wrap my head around how it needed to be done. Thanks again for your help and the code sample.